# Xojo Count Words in HTML - Remove Tags & Other Unwanted Content That May Skew Count?

Tags: html, xojo

I've inserted some temporary inside the action event of a timer which converts markdown to html as you type the markdown. This event places the html in the variable mHTML.

I wanting to count the words in the text and display those in a  label. I am defining a word as one or more printable characters which do not include html tags.

This code first grabs the html from the variable mHTML. I then use Regex to remove any tags. I then use Regex to replace one or more end of lines with a single space. I then use Regex to replace one or more spaces with a single space. I then trim any spaces from the beginning or end string. I then count the number of spaces in the string and add 1 to get a word count which is displayed within a label in the app window.

I also added some code to copy the cleanup text in which I counting spaces to the clipboard to examine how my code is doing.

What would be a more efficient to way to do this. There is code above and below the code I added that can't be changed. The code above what I added includes code that that places the HTML into the variable mHTML.

```
-Code Above Here-

Dim re As New RegEx
re.SearchPattern = "<[^<>]+>"
re.ReplacementPattern = ""
re.Options.ReplaceAllMatches = True

Dim html As String = mHTML
Dim plain As String = re.Replace(html)

re.SearchPattern = "\n+"
re.ReplacementPattern = " "
re.Options.ReplaceAllMatches = True

plain = re.Replace(plain)

re.SearchPattern = "\s+"
re.ReplacementPattern = " "
re.Options.ReplaceAllMatches = True

plain = re.Replace(plain)
plain = trim(plain)

Dim MCount as Integer = CountFields(plain, " ")
Dim C as New Clipboard
C.Text = plain

Label.Text = Str(MCount + 1)

-More Code Below Here-
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the procedure for removing the tags is sound, unless there are ">" characters inside strings inside the tags, but I'm not sure if that's even allowed.

Are you doing this on a macOS or Linux system?

Then you could try using the cmdline tool `wc` to count the words, by passing the text without the tags to it. Use the Shell class to invoke the tool, and either pass the text via stdin to it or save the text to a temporary file and pass its path to the command. But first try out the `wc` command in a terminal manually to see if it even gives you the expected results.